# Is it possible to Html Encode content that may or may not alreayd be encoded cleanly?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I'm using ASP.Net 4.0 with MVC 2. I'm recieving user content that may or may not be Html Encoded already. I've read http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx which was interesting but what I need is a way to ensure the content is encoded without double encoding. I don't have control of the input process.

E.g.

User Input:

```
&amp; &lt; < > &gt;
```

Output if encoded:

```
&amp;amp; &amp;lt; &lt; &gt; &amp;gt;
```

Won't display correctly

Output if not encoded:

```
&amp; &lt; < > &gt;
```

This won't validate correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will find a solution which will work automatically both for content that is encoded and not - the only way I can see where you can do this reliably is to specify whether the content has been encoded or not.  Otherwise, you will run into problems in certain situations, e.g.

```
Some plain text mentioning &gt; being the syntax for >
```

And

```
<p>Some HTML mentioning that &amp;amp; is the syntax for &gt;</p>
```

You can try detecting whether there is encoded content or HTML content present, but my examples above show that this will not always be infallible.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a first pass decoding user input, and then re-encode the result.
This way, if some values of the input are already encoded, they will get decoded, and you'll be able to encode everything after.

```
&amp; &lt; < > &gt;
```

-> decode the input and you get:

```
& < < > >
```

-> re-encode everything and you get:

```
&amp; &lt; &lt; &gt; &gt
```

Comment: This would fail on plain text content mentioning a HTML entity, as it would be decoded when this wasn't the intention.

Comment: You are right.  I guess it depends of the kind of input he'll get.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd replace only the `<` and `>` characters, leaving everything else intact.